# How do I make a dynamic div curve in a way that follows a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to simulate a cable hanging between two points in a 2D space. To make the cable, I would like to be able to create a div that curves in a way that represents a catenary (though a parabola is fine).

I can't use an svg or and image, however, because I want the two points that the cable hangs from to be able to be moved by the user. How would I do this?

Comment: You might have to use canvas for something like this... I'm not completely understanding your requirements, but it sounds like it might be beyond what you can accomplish with HTML/CSS alone.  While there are ways to alter the shape of a div to some degree, the complexity of the transformation you are discussing, plus the user interaction, makes it sound like canvas might be a better fit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Comment: a div is a rectangle and stays one... you might want to use canvas for this

Comment: take a look at this... maybe it helps you understand the basics: https://codepen.io/guerrillacontra/pen/XPZeww

Comment: "I want the two points that the cable hangs from to be able to be moved by the user" this is still achievable with an SVG.